# Name of rubber "sandwich" between PCB and LCD?

Tags: connector

In taking apart my moribund wall thermostat I found a conductive rubber-ish connector between the PCB and LCD panel. It's cool stuff!

What's it called?

Comment: [It's called *zebra strip* or *elastomeric connector*.](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/102118/7036)  This question was asked a few times here already.  But, if one doesn't know what it's called, one can not find the old questions.

Answer (score 0):

It is called an Elastomeric connector.