# What are types of connection between metallic conductors and glass part of an LCD?

Tags: connector, lcd, conductors

I know that [elastomeric connectors](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/102118/17817) are being used to connect metallic conductors to the conductive paths on the glass part of an LCD but there must be other ways being commonly used. For example in iPhone there seems to be no space for the elastomeric connector. See the fifth image here: [Can an ordinary Joe replace a busted iPhone screen?](http://www.cnet.com/how-to/can-an-ordinary-joe-replace-a-busted-iphone-5s-screen/)

What are other commonly used types of such connections and how difficult is to disconnect and reconnect them at home?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The conductors one the glass cannot be soldered to, so a few methods are used.

On big crude displays, metal spring pins are glomped onto the edge of the glass and secured with (usually clear) epoxy.

On smaller displays, elastomeric (Zebra) connectors are often used.

Another method (suitable for the highest densities) is to heat seal an FPC (flex circuit) to the glass with conductive adhesive. Sometimes the FPC contains active components, other times it's just a jumper.

It's not at all practical to remove this from the glass, or replace them for a one-off, you should replace the entire display- usually the other end of the FPC goes into a socket. If it's heat sealed onto a PCB that's going to be more difficult, but that would be the end to be fiddled with.

**If** you had the exact replacement FPC (not likely), it might be possible to fiddle around with a well controlled hot air gun and re-laminate the exact replacement cable with the appropriate equipment creating the proper temperature and pressure to get a reliable bond, but that seems quite unlikely to turn out well without proper equipment and jigs for the particular display.

Comment: I once tried to reglue an fpc to an LCD display using a hot air gun and plenty of patience. Saying "quite unlikely" is an euphemism.

Comment: @VladimirCravero Thanks for the data point. ;-) People have done some amazing things with limited equipment and lots of skill and knowledge. Remove with the hot air. Machine up a bar with a small cartridge heater, spring load it in an arbor press and control the temperature with a thermocouple and PID controller. It's not rocket science, but it's also not worth the time/cost/hassles unless you're making thousands.

Comment: What does "to glomp" mean?

Comment: @starblue To glomp is to hug (as with your arms, a bit slang-y). The terminals are springy and hug both sides of the glass to make a connection with the indium-tin-oxide (ITO) traces (usually the conductor is only on one side). http://www.yidong.com.cn/en/Photo/UploadPhotos/LCD%E7%AB%AF%E5%AD%90-new/130x87/06.jpg